# Laravel Spark upload profile picture to external driver

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-spark

I want to override the way Laravel Spark save the profile picture of a user to use an external driver such as S3 for example. I already have my S3 config for the bucket I want to use. What would be the best way to do this? Should I use a completely different route and use a custom endpoint or is there a config somewhere I could change so that Spark uses a different driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ended up doing this

I added these methods in update-profile-photo.js

```
methods: {
    updateProfilePhoto() {

        axios.post('/settings/profile/details/profile-picture', this.gatherFormData())
            .then(
                () => {
                    console.log('Profile picture updated');
                    Bus.$emit('updateUser');

                    self.form.finishProcessing();
                },
                (error) => {
                    self.form.setErrors(error.response.data.errors);
                }
            );
    },
    gatherFormData() {
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append('photo', this.$refs.photo.files[0]);

        return data;
    }
}
```

And my Controller looked like this

```
public function updateProfilePicture(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'photo' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Storing the photo
    //get filename with extension
    $filenamewithextension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();

    //get filename without extension
    $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

    //get file extension
    $extension = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    //filename to store
    $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

    Storage::disk('s3_users')->put($filenametostore, fopen($request->file('photo'), 'r+'), 'public');

    $url = $filenametostore;

    $request->user()->forceFill([
        'image_url' => $url
    ])->save();


    return response()->json(
        array(
            "message" => "Profile picture was updated!",
        )
    );

}
```